# Drupal Commerce - Paypal Payment

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, sandbox, drupal-commerce

I'm looking for a explanation about how the Paypal Sandbox works. Let's say I have a real Paypal account through which I receive payments and I want to configure it on Drupal Commerce's Paypal module, but also I want to test the payment workflow first before making it live and let my customers use it, I see the Paypal configuration on Drupal has the following options under the "PayPal server" section:

- Sandbox - use for testing, requires a PayPal Sandbox account
- Live - use for processing real transactions

I assume that if I want to do "dummy" transactions I must enable the "Sandbox" option on the Drupal side so my question is

*Is enabling the 'Sandbox' option the only thing I need to do in order to avoid real transactions being charged to my Paypal account? or do I have to create another Paypal account (the Sandbox account) and configure it on the Drupal side instead of my real account?*

I was just wondering if the Paypal Payment plugin on Drupal needs a "Sandbox account" (different from my real Paypal account) or if by just enabling the Sandbox option it somehow signals Paypal about it and any transactions are just ignored while that option is enabled.

I'll apreciate if someone clarifies this a bit for me, I'm just starting to develop Paypal related stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has already been addressed here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694105/how-to-set-up-a-paypal-sandbox-seller-account-a-buyer-account-and-an-applic

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a sandbox account from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_signup-run)

You cannot test a dummy transaction with a real PayPal account on PayPal Sandbox. It requires Sandbox account. So, you need a Sandbox account AND change the Drupal option to Sandbox for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't quite answers my question. What I want to know is how the options I outlined above from the Drupal Paypal Payment settings work.

Comment: Thanks for updating your response, so based on that what is the difference if I use a real Paypal account and enable the "Sandbox" option in Drupal? will it send real transactions although the "Sandbox" option is selected?. I thought the idea of the "Sandbox" option in Drupal was to always have the real Paypal account configured and only "switch" between "Sandbox" and "Live" when needed

Comment: I haven't tried but probably, after you enable the Sandbox option in Drupal, then you'll not be able to complete the transaction with real account (may be you'll get authentication failure etc.)