# How to set up a PayPal sandbox "Seller" account, a "Buyer" account and an Application Tutorial

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to set up a Web site which is using PayPal. Unfortunately the PayPal developer site/concept is heavily changed, so all tutorials I found are seem to be useless. For example this (very good) [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEhUOGW9nLc) which is very clear is using not existing pages and functions...

So please try to help me only with up to date information/tutorial.

Please note my questions is not about using API, it is about how to set up an app, and a testing sandbox configuration from the ground.

1) As far as I understand I must have a *real* PayPal account because dev site uses PayPal account for logon (new). Logged in with this account then I can create sandbox accounts. However I would like to create a "Seller" sandbox account and a "Buyer" sandbox account. (missed I something?) Using the new developer site it is not possible. I can create only one kind of sandbox account. In the referenced video there are two types of sandbox accounts: "seller" and "buyer" in the preconfigured accounts. Or "Seller" simply means Business account?

2) I must have an application id to use the API. Note: I inherited a working legacy code which is using the classic API, so no REST please. In the video (old PayPal dev site) there is a left side menu "API and Payment Card credentials" In the new PayPal dev site no such thing. Instead there is a "My Apps".

I've tried to set up an application. It approved automatically. In its metadata I see a live and a sandbox app id.

What is not clear: To what account is associated this newly created app? I've created it logged in with my real paypal credentials. 
More: ??? When filling the app creation form there was an input field titled: "Supply Test Account Name and Password". First of all how can I type the name *and* a password to *one* input field? Secondly What is it? Maybe if I use this app with its sandbox app id then this account will be the Seller (got the money) and if I change the app id to the live one associated this app, then my real PayPal account got the money?

However my goal was to completely simulate the payment process so

1) Create a Seller sandbox account (got API credentials)
2) Associate an application to that Seller account, and get the app id.
3) Create a buyer sandbox account

4a) Configure my web site with Seller API credentials and sandbox app id
4b) Orchestrate a buy process using my website, PayPal API and the 2 sandbox account

5) Check the Seller and Buyer sandbox account's transactions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yould cou take a look [on this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556870/missingcredentialexception-no-api-accounts-have-been-configured-in-application)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seller account = Business account

Buyer account = Personal account

You probably only need to create one of each in [Developer Sandbox Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts) , but there's no limit if your testing requires some more

To obtain the new REST API credentials, create an App in [My Apps & Credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications) and select the sandbox Business account to use

**Legacy APIs**: If testing an old integration (pre-REST API), you can still get Classic NVP/SOAP credentials for a business account by clicking on its 3 dots menu within your list of sandbox accounts -> View/Edit account -> API Credentials

Comment: i tried to followed your way, but it didt worked for me. means i can't see "create account" button

Comment: @Preston Alexander I have successfully created payment to a sandbox paypal app. And when I check the `Transaction` in paypal, all the transaction logs are shown. But there is no change in either buyer's amount or facilitator's amount? I don't know whether the values get updated or not. 
I used `create()` method. Do I also need to use `execute()` method?

Comment: @viper the steps for a new transaction are (1) create, (2) approve (redirect buyer to PayPal.com for approval) (3) execute

Comment: Thank you. I had solved the problem when using `paypal` payment but `Buyer` 's amount doesn't get deducted when using `cards` as a payment option.

Comment: Is there a chance that you can help me [on this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556870/missingcredentialexception-no-api-accounts-have-been-configured-in-application)?

Answer (score 5):

Just found myself in the same situation. Like you say it seems to be constantly evolving - not even sure if some of the answers here are still up to date.

Walked through it like this:

1. Login at developer.paypal.com
2. Go to Applications tab
3. Click on the Sandbox accounts on the left hand side
4. Any sandbox accounts you already created will be listed. Big blue button **Create Account** to create more

[image]

Comment: i tried to followed your way, but it didt worked for me. means i can't see "create account" button.

Comment: Is there a chance that you can help me [on this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556870/missingcredentialexception-no-api-accounts-have-been-configured-in-application)?

Answer (score 3):

Think of logging in to the sandbox with your real PayPal account as logging into your Sandbox.  You do this at http://developer.paypal.com.

Once you are logged into your sandbox in the middle of the screen, click on "continue testing using Sandbox test accounts".

When the next screen comes up you will see a heading of Sandbox Test Accounts and to the far right of that a button to Create Account.  Click on this and then you need to create a "Personal" buyer account (your sandbox buyer who you will test with) and a "Business" seller account (your sandbox seller who you will test with).

Set up each one of these as if you were setting up a new Paypal account.

When you have them created fully you will have fictitious bank accounts to work with.

Beyond that, you may wish to check out these tutorials http://www.developphp.com/list_php_video.php where the site goes in-depth with setting up PayPal payments on a website using your own custom, basic shopping cart with a PayPal IPN (instant payment notification). You want to scroll down to the "E-Commerce Website Tutorial...".  Lessons 9-20 deal with the cart and accepting PayPal.  This may be an older way to do things, but it will help you get a general grounding in working with PayPal IMHO.

You also can visit https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/  At the bottom of the column is a heading "Classic API's" that may provide the documentation you are looking for to move forward.

Good Luck!